# How small (in modulus) can a polynomial get?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, approximation-theory

> **Question.** If $f(z)\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ is a [monic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) of degree $n$, is it true that
>   $$\max\{\,\vert f(x)\vert: \, -1\leq x\leq 1\}\geq 2^{1-n} \,\, ?$$

*Context.* This came up while working on some [convexity problems](https://www.math.temple.edu/~tewodros/Catalan_Convexity.pdf).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Proved by Chebyshev. The extreme case ($\max = 2^{1-n}$) is given by $2^{n-1}\cdot f(x)$ being a Chebyshev polynomial of first kind.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: Okay. Any reference?

Comment: Check the lead section of Wikipedia.

Comment: Cool. Maybe one adds a line of argument to complex polynomials. But, that is okay.

Comment: Interpolate your polynomial in the extrema points of $T_n$ and look at the leading coefficient.

Answer (score 5):

You are essentially asking to approximate $x^n$ on $[-1,1]$ by a polynomial of degree less than $n$.  The Remez algorithm will find the best possible aproximation.  In Maple you can enter

`numapprox[minimax](x^n,x=-1..1,[n-1,0]);`

If you take $n=10$ or so and work to 100 digits you will quickly convince yourself that the maximum error is precisely $2^{1-n}$.  It also looks as though the optimal approximation $f(x)$ has $2^{1-n}f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  One could probably find a formula for the coefficients experimentally with the help of OEIS and then work back to a proper proof.  But sadly I need to go and do less interesting things now.